# How to pass my object into another objects field?

Tags: java, oop

I am trying to fill `UCFCourse courseOne` in my constructor with a `courses[]` object in `fillWithCourses()`.`UCFCourse courseOne` does populate outside of the constructor but will not go into it.

```
public class UCFSemester<courses> {

private static UCFCourse courseOne;
private static double totalSemesters;
private static double completionTime;
static boolean fillSemester = true;

public UCFSemester(UCFCourse courseOne, UCFCourse[] coursetwo) {
    this.courseOne = courseOne;
}

public static UCFCourse getcourseOne() {
    return courseOne;
}

public static void setCoursesone(UCFCourse courses) {
    courseOne = courses;
}

public static void fillWithCourses(UCFCourse courses[], int l) {
    int x = 0;
    while (fillSemester) {
        for (int n = 0; n < 5; n++) {
            if (x != n && courses[x].getCourseLevel() < courses[n].getCourseLevel()) {
                setCoursesone(courses[x]);
            }
        }
        fillSemester = false;
    }

}

}
```

Side question.How can I access this all in a non-static way?I need the entire thing to be non-static but no matter what I do I can't get it.Thanks!

Comment: `"Please if you see syntax errors show me whats right!"` -- your compiler will show you all syntax errors, and you should strive to fix them first before coming here. Your use of generics appears to be way off. What are you trying to achieve with a generic parameter? You don't appear to be using a valid type for this parameter. What errors are you But putting that aside, what are you trying to achieve with all of this?

Comment: Its just a project idea.Im having fun making it but I am having a difficult time putting one object into another objects field.It sucks that this wont get answered and only down voted because I can only ask what people think are "good questions".

Comment: Rather than complain -- read up on what makes questions good and fix it. For example, you mention syntax errors, and again the compiler will show these to you, **but you don't show any of this information with your question** -- why? Please improve the question.

Comment: Also, and again, please explain that generic. You appear to have a method parameter variable (not type!) with the same name as the generic type which is a bit odd.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm extremely new to this.I have literally just started playing around with objects.I am unsure what you're even referring to.I was hoping I could get some assistance and move in the proper direction.

Comment: It is not about being hard-nosed. People like to help, for free. With the volume of questions there is, if you don't think out your problem clearly how come people can help you? Some questions seem to be asked by bots

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it by creating a `List` like this:

```
public class UCFSemester {
    private List<UCFCourse> courseList = new ArrayList<>();

    public UCFCourse getCourse(int index) {
        return courseList.get(index);
    }

    public void addCourses(UCFCourse[] courses) {
        for(int x = 0; x < courses.length; x++) {
            courseList.add(courses[x]);
        }
    }
}
```

Here, I'm assuming that you are passing the `UCFCourse[]` array with all the course details that are there in that particular semester.

`addCourses()` function will take this array and then add all the corresponding courses to the `List`.

`getCourse()` function will return you any particular course from the List (Using Index). You can also modify the search in any way you want.